Technique for finding expected value Weighted Ridge Regression Coefficients
Context: We would like to approximate a linear function $f(\mathbf{x})$ at the point $\boldsymbol{\xi} \in \mathbb{R}^D$ using samples of size $N$ around $\boldsymbol{\xi}$. Assume that the input data to $f$ are i.i.d. standard $D$-variate normal. So given a sample data matrix $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times D}$, we produce a diagonal weight matrix $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ for the samples. Weighted ridge regression has the solution form
$$\mathbf{\hat{u}} = (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1}(\mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{y})$$
where $\lambda$ is the ridge penalty and $\mathbf{y}$ is the response vector.
Question: How would I find the expected value of $\mathbf{\hat{u}}$ over possible samples  $\mathbf{X}$? The rows of such matrices are to be sampled i.i.id. such that the $n$th row is distributed according to $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\xi}, 1)$.
Attempt: I have seen the following type of argument employed.

Define $\boldsymbol{\hat{\Sigma}} = \frac{1}{N} (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X} + \lambda \mathbf{I})$ and $\boldsymbol{\hat{\Gamma}} = \frac{1}{N}\mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{y}$
Declare $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}:=\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\hat{\Sigma}}]$ and $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}:=\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\hat{\Gamma}}]$ to be the population counterparts
Compute $\boldsymbol{\hat{\Sigma}}$, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\Gamma}}$, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}$, and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \Gamma$.
Show that $||\boldsymbol{\hat{\Sigma}} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}||$, $||\boldsymbol{\hat{\Gamma}} - \boldsymbol{\Gamma}||$, and $||\boldsymbol{\hat{u}} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\Gamma}||$ are small

I have done all of the steps except for the last one. I am uncertain about the following.

I don't think there should be any factors of $N$ in $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$, but my solution has an $N$ in it.
How do I justify that $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$ is the expected value of $\boldsymbol{\hat{u}}$?

